# How to change coupon error message in magento 2.3 accourding to conditions

Tags: magento2.3

I want to show message "Coupon already used" If coupon limit/used by customer instead of "The coupon code isnt valid."

But Didnt know how to add this condition.
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Have you ever find solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Path for the core file for set coupon details:

"project\vendor\magento\module-sales-rule\view\frontend\web\js\action\set-coupon-code.js"

You can extend this file and can change the message like this:

```
    this file consist of this code:
        /**
         * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
         * See COPYING.txt for license details.
         */

        /**
         * Customer store credit(balance) application
         */
    define([
        'ko',
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/resource-url-manager',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor',
        'Magento_SalesRule/js/model/payment/discount-messages',
        'mage/storage',
        'mage/translate',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-payment-information',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader'
    ], function (ko, $, quote, urlManager, errorProcessor, messageContainer, storage, $t, getPaymentInformationAction,
        totals, fullScreenLoader
    ) {
        'use strict';

        return function (couponCode, isApplied) {
            var quoteId = quote.getQuoteId(),
                url = urlManager.getApplyCouponUrl(couponCode, quoteId),
                message = $t('Your coupon was successfully applied.');

            fullScreenLoader.startLoader();

            return storage.put(
                url,
                {},
                false
            ).done(function (response) {
                var deferred;

                if (response) {
                    deferred = $.Deferred();

                    isApplied(true);
                    totals.isLoading(true);
                    getPaymentInformationAction(deferred);
                    $.when(deferred).done(function () {
                        fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
                        totals.isLoading(false);
                    });
                    messageContainer.addSuccessMessage({
                        'message': message
                    });
                }
            }).fail(function (response) {

//changes starts for add custom error msg


            var newerrormessage = $t("dasdasdasdasdadasdsa");
            messageContainer.addErrorMessage({
                    'message': newerrormessage 
                });

//changes end 

                fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
                totals.isLoading(false);
                errorProcessor.process(response, messageContainer);
            });
        };
    });
```

after this comment "//changes starts for add custom error msg" you can set the new msg like shown in code like that by adding a new error message using  "messageContainer" object.

Comment: Thanks for answer @nihal , I want message according to conditions .. mean "Coupon already used ", "In valid coupon"

Comment: yeah you can add a condition or use the success or failure condition to show your message already defined in this code.
1.if you want to add a message when coupon succesfully applied, change the text in **message** variable.
2.if you want to add a message when coupon applied failed, change the text in **newerrormessage** variable.

Comment: no not success message. If customer has reached coupon to  limit "Want to show message Coupon used" ... If coupon doesnt exit .. "In valid copon" I want coupon valtion with msg